# Referencing .Net Core project from .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-maui

I have 2 projects in my solution - .Net Maui(GUI) and ASP.Net Core Web API(API)

After adding a project reference to my GUI I get the following errors:

[image: reference error]

And I can find very little information on that, although I'm probably looking in wrong places. Can you give a hand with that?

Edit:
To complete/expand my question, I'm looking for a way to structer my solution a little bit better, I don't want to have everything in .NET Maui project.
I was following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrZwd-f0M4I
The author does create .NET Core project for API and Db connection
(EF Core) and then he uses the Api in .NET Maui

What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you trying to blend the 2 types? What are you wanting to accomplish

Comment: Hi @DanielA.White thanks for replying. I don't know what do you mean by "blending 2 types". I want to get access to my entity placed in Api project, that's all.

Comment: From what i watch briefly on the long video, the two solutions (projects) API and MAUI don't have a dependency reference between each other

Comment: Are you trying to have both depend on a common class library? Or have one directly depend on the other? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: @mason Ideally I would like to have something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YiVqwoFMieg I'm just looking for a way to properly structer my solution.

Comment: You're saying you want to do it like Nick Chapsas. Great, he's a smart guy. But that doesn't really tell us what you did. If you want to share code from two apps, then put the common code in a class library, and have both apps reference that. Is that what you did? Or did you have one of the app projects try to reference the other?

Comment: @mason Sorry for late response. I have .NET Maui project, and I'm trying to reference some classes in .Net Core project, where I have my API and Db, but I can't because of the error. So what project type should I create to be able to keep my MAUI App separeted from my API and Db? Because seems that, this is the thing which confuses me the most.

Comment: .NET Core is fine, but there is absolutely no reason for your MAUI app to reference an API project. If they need to share common code, then create a 3rd class library project, and have both your API and your MAUI app reference that.

Comment: Though to be honest, a MAUI project probably shouldn't have any direct database access anyways. The MAUI app can consume the API app via HTTP (or gRPC), and the API app is the only one that needs direct access to the database. There's exceptions of course, but it doesn't sound like your app falls into one of those exceptions.

Comment: @mason Ok. I'll try it this way then. Thank you for your efforts, trying to explain it to me, really appreciate it!